# loop through multiple directories and read a html file for status

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I need to grep "status" from multiple report.html and make a combined report, these reports are saved in below directories. All directories highlighted with ** is different for each report. How could I achieve this. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs**E2E_Sanity**\jobs**ABC_E2E_Sanity**\builds**41**\archive\performanceTestsReports**pcRun106821**\Report

Comment: With a for loop? Can you give more détails on your current implementation?

Comment: Python Java Groovy... Choose one

Answer (score 0):

For example using python and the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob

files = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs*\jobs*\builds*\archive\performanceTestsReports*\Report"
l = glob.glob(files)
for f in l:
    print (f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a small groovy program that can:

- extract fix row numbers (if the status is at fixed row)
- search for a word - status and extract the information

  ```
  int lineNo = 1
  //if the row number is fixed you can extracted by minLine and maxLine
  int minLine = 1
  int maxLine = 20
  def line
  def status
  def statusRegex


  def folder = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ero")

  folder.eachFile{it->
  println "File: ${it.absolutePath}"

  it.withReader { reader->
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null & lineNo <= maxLine) {

          if (lineNo >= minLine) {
              //        println "${lineNo}. ${line}" //if you need specific line numbers
          }
          lineNo++
          //search for status and print the line
          status = line.find("status")
          //search for status by regex and extract all up to <
          statusRegex = line.find(/(?s)status (.*?)\</)

          if(status){
              println '    full line' + line
          }
          if(statusRegex){
              println '    by regex' + statusRegex
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```